# How to dynamically add vertical line to kendo-chart with c# mvc wrappers?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've created a kendo chart in my c# mvc web application and would like to draw a simple vertical line (e.g. plotband) dynamically when a slider value changes. The slider change function, as well as drawing the plotbands statically works, but when I try to draw it dynamically on the change-event of the slider it doesn't do anything.

The chart is initialized with mvc-wrappers in the following way:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<ViewModel>()
 .Name("stretchAltitudeProfile")
 .Series(series =>
    {
        series.ScatterLine(m => m.xlab, m => m.value).Name("Stretch").Color("#ff1c1c").Markers(markers => markers.Visible(false)).Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{1:n0}m @ {0}m"));
    })
    .YAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric("Altitude Height")
        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0} m"))
        .Color("#73c100")
    )
    .XAxis(x => x

            .Numeric()
            .PlotBands(bands => bands.Add().From(300).To(500).Color("#c00"))
            .Title(title => title.Text("Stretch Length m"))
            .Crosshair(c => c.Visible(true))
            .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:No}m").Rotation(-45))
    )
```

The slider change function in the javascript looks as follows:

```
function sliderChange(e) {
  var chart = $("#stretchAltitudeProfile").data("kendoChart");
  chart.setOptions({
        xAxis: {
            plotBands: [
                { from: 100, to: 200, color: "red" }
            ]
  }
 chart.refresh();
}
```

Unfortunately nothing changes when this function is being called. What's the proper way to call the setOptions function of the chart when using mvc wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing some brackets/braces:

```
chart.setOptions({
        xAxis: {
            plotBands: [
                { from: val, to: val+2, color: "red" }
            ]
        }
})
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vvjPpg)**

NOTE: in the demo I also turn off animations so the chart redraw happens faster.

```
transitions: false,
```

Comment: I've tried it that way, but it seems the problem is that I cannot change any chart properties when using mvc-wrappers instead of using a plain html-placeholder + javascript like you did.

Comment: @mhfmn, I have not used the mvc wrappers myself. hopefully someone else will chime in...